# Materialize CSS Select not Closing after selecting element

Tags: drop-down-menu, tabs, materialize

I am using materialize css. I created a tab and put select element inside it. But it was not closing after selecting element.I am using materialize 0.98.

If i put it outside tab then it works.

Here is my code :

My Scrtipt

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(e) {
            $('ul.tabs').tabs({'swipeable': true});
            $("select").material_select();
        });
    </script>
```

Html Code :

```
<div class="main mainContentMargin">
            <div class="row">
                <!-- This will Work-->
                <div class="col s12 input-field">
                    <select id="company_select1" name="company_select1">
                        <option value="-1" selected>Select Company</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                    </select>
                    <label>Select Company</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="card col s12 medium">
                    <ul id="tabs-swipe-demo" class="tabs tabs-fixed-width" style="margin-bottom: 1%">
                        <li class="tab col s6"><a href="#test-swipe-1">To Supplier</a></li>
                        <li class="tab col s6"><a href="#test-swipe-2">Using Product</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div id="test-swipe-1" class="col s12">
                        <!-- This will Work but not closing the dropdown-->
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col s12 input-field">
                                <select id="company_select" name="company_select">
                                    <option value="-1" selected>Select Company</option>                                                                                 
                                            <option value="1">1</option>
                                            <option value="2">2</option>
                                </select>
                                <label>Select Company</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="test-swipe-2" class="col s12">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dropdown is not closing because we make tab swipeable. That's why it dropdown click event was catched by the tab.

I just set the stopPropogation option to true in dropdown and it work

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('ul.tabs').tabs({'swipeable': true});
    $("select").material_select({"stopPropagation":true});
});
```